# Java http request on binary file - can't read correct content-length

Tags: java, sockets, binary

I'm sending a http request to get binary files (here i'm trying an image)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        new Main(args);

    }

    public Main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        lance(args);
    }

    private void lance(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Lanceur lan = new Lanceur("www.cril.univ-artois.fr", "/IMG/arton451.jpg");
        lan.requete();
    }

}

public class Lanceur {

    Socket s;
    InputStream readStream;
    OutputStream writeStream;
    String host;
    String ressource;

    public Lanceur(String host, String ressource) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), 80);
        readStream = s.getInputStream();
        writeStream = s.getOutputStream();
        this.host = host;
        this.ressource = ressource;
    }

    public void requete() throws IOException {
        // String[] length = null;
        writeStream.write(new String("GET " + ressource + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                + "Host: www.google.com\r\n" + "\r\n").getBytes());
        writeStream.flush();
        AnswerReader as = new AnswerReader(readStream);
        as.read();
        as.writeFile(this.ressource);
        s.close();
    }
}

public class AnswerReader {
    BufferedReader br;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String status;
    Map<String, String> attrs;
    byte[] content;

    public AnswerReader(InputStream is) {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
    }

    public void read() throws NumberFormatException {
        readStatus();
        try {
            readAttrs();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String contentL = attrs.get("Content-Length");

        readContent(Integer.valueOf(contentL));

    }

    public void readStatus() {
        try {
            status = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readAttrs() throws IOException {
        attrs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String line;

        for (line = br.readLine(); line.length() > 0; line = br.readLine()) {
            int index = line.indexOf(':');
            attrs.put(line.substring(0, index), line.substring(index + 2));
        }
    }

    private void readContent(int size) {

        this.content = new byte[size];
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int copied = 0;
        int read = 0;
        while (copied < size) {
            try {
                read = dis.read(buff);
                if (read == -1)
                    break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // byte[] byteArray = new String(buff).getBytes();
            System.arraycopy(buff, 0, content, copied, read);
            copied += read;
        }
        System.out.println(copied + "///" + size);
    }

    public void writeFile(String name) throws IOException {
        String tab[] = name.split("/");
        String filename = tab[tab.length - 1];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./" + filename);
        fos.write(content);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

The problem comes from readContent(). The content-length is fine, but it doesn't read all the data. From this example it will reads that :

```
22325///38125
```

Comment: Is the data missing from the start or the end of `content`. I'm wondering if the `BufferedReader` you are using to read by line is consuming some of the content data since it could read beyond the next newline (depending on the default buffer size).

Answer (score 0):

The `BufferedReader` is buffering some of the binary data. You'll have to find another way to read the header lines using the unbuffered input stream instead, e.g. `DataInputStream.readLine()`, deprecation or no.

But you should use `HttpURLConnection`. It's easier.